# How to store XML elements in App.config file

Tags: c#, xml, app-config

I want to store a private key in an app.config file

here is a sample private key

```
<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>vht+dSDSL/4IOJ0i5k4FKLTl5hFqEU60AMP53QQNB1pG+lvlACALUtWoIVgjxFQoutQlSbuxTpynjeLwnmCu70F7qprDM0QiXLvZ/v8kMFYDHkBBpHd273mcGcYTwicXNhNywbhqim72gPhZJhJelIJY4Wi7QBf6SaGV6f6HzGE=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>
```

I want to store in following code

```
  <appSettings>
<add key="PrivateKey" value="" />
```

How to do this? When paste the code here it give me errors. Also how to read it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to XML-encode the attribute value - specifically, `<` becomes `&lt;` and `>` becomes `&gt;`:

```
<add 
    key="PrivateKey" 
    value="&lt;RSAKeyValue&gt;&lt;Modulus&gt;vht+dSDSL/4IOJ0i5k4FKLTl5hFqEU60AMP53QQNB1pG+lvlACALUtWoIVgjxFQoutQlSbuxTpynjeLwnmCu70F7qprDM0QiXLvZ/v8kMFYDHkBBpHd273mcGcYTwicXNhNywbhqim72gPhZJhJelIJY4Wi7QBf6SaGV6f6HzGE=&lt;/Modulus&gt;&lt;Exponent&gt;AQAB&lt;/Exponent&gt;&lt;/RSAKeyValue&gt;" 
/>
```

[List of XML and HTML character entity references - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)